# Jquery does not work in 0.10 sails

Tags: jquery, sails.js

(Sorry for my English)

I am new Sails, and I'm trying to use jquery. Following the steps in this [Tutorial of YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wL2cS0GmJQ&list=PLf8i4fc0zJBzLhOe6FwHpGhBDgqwInJWZ&index=10). But I made ​​it through and as the tutorial is in version 0.9 and I am working on 0.10 where the linker does not exist and could not achieve using jquery.

---

In my loyout.ejs before the

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the view I have this structure

- views

  - users

    - new.ejs

Where I'm trying to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').text('hello world'); 
 } 
</script> 

<p id="test"> aaa </p>
```

And in the controller UsersController.js I have this:

```
module.exports = {
 new: function(req, res) {
  res.view(); 
 } 
};
```

What I try to achieve is to change the p element

loading page with "hello world" to realize that jQuery is already running.

---

And I get the typical error saying jQuery is not working.

I appreciate your help. 
Thank you!

---

loyout.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>App sails</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="/styles/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/styles/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--<script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>-->

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <!--<script src="/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      alert('hola');
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap theme</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

      <%- body %>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
<!--
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>

<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/customValidate.js"></script>
<script src="/js/docs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>-->
<!--SCRIPTS END-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no spaces in file paths.

Comment: And you are missing a lot of points `.`

Comment: Excuse me, is that I'm helping a translator, and edit it.

Comment: Please paste all your code and the error you are getting.
Español: Por favor copia y pega todo el código y el error que estás obteniendo.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you stored the jQuery source into `assets/js/jquery.min.js`.

If it's there, make sure you load jQuery at the *top* of `layouts.ejs` (at the very least, *before* your jQuery script is used, especially if you're using the jQuery code in other view files (i.e. the body):

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  ..
  /** your jQuery script use **/
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried and putting it at the end and at the beginning and still does not work. 

And of course if in assets / js 

I see that in version 0.9 and linker used Gruntfile.js but this removed in the new version I'm using. Is there something similar I should do?

Comment: Linker was removed in Sails 0.10.x but the Gruntfile still loads the asset files, although at the end of the layout file. Can you edit your post to include the entire current layouts.ejs file?

Comment: Can you press "F12" after you load the page, click "console", and copy the error messages here? Loading jQuery at the top in the head and running your script works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the replies and comments. Me and I noticed 2 things to solve my problem.

1. Sails implemented at the end of loyout.ejs jQuery by default and for this reason does not work, but must be at the beginning.
2. I had to remove other plugins that were causing conflicts.